# Monero local node: block set up

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-size

I've used Bitcoin before, but I'm on my third day of trying to figure out Monero. I tried to set up a local node on a separate computer, but it took a few days to synchronize. Then I got tired of waiting and read that you can set the block height and start synchronizing from there. With Web-node it works, but with local node it starts synchronizing not from say 3113000 block, but as if from the beginning, on another computer the progress started from the middle somewhere. It is necessary to download much more data! Why can't I synchronize everything starting from block 3113000? What am I doing wrong?
When I started with the 3113000 block, I was surprised by this output:

```
>>> status

[3/27/24 11:13 AM] 2024-03-27 11:13:08.101 I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.2-release)
Height: 272740/3114197 (8.8%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 17.01 MH/s, v1, 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 3m 1s
```

Why not 3113000/3114197? Why i strating from 272740 block?